# Ajax com checkbox html

Tags: php, html, ajax

Estou com problema para pegar o valor do checkbox selecionado, o php está pegando o valor de todos os checkbox inclusive dos que não foram selecionados.

**Como faria para o Ajax passar pro PHP apenas os que forem selecionados?**

**HTML Formulário:**

```
<form method="post" action="javascript:;" id="form_cadastro" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="nenhum_tipo" value="nenhum_tipo">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="nenhum_tipo">Nenhum</label><br>

    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Bloco_1" value="Bloco_1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="Bloco_1">Bloco 1 </label><br>

    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Bloco_2" value="Bloco_2">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="Bloco_2">Bloco 2 </label><br>

    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Bloco_3" value="Bloco_3">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="Bloco_3">Bloco 3 </label><br>

    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Bloco_4" value="Bloco_4">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="Bloco_4">Bloco 4 </label><br>

    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Bloco_5" value="Bloco_5">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="Bloco_5">Bloco 5 </label>
  </div>

</form>
```

**Ajax JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#form_cadastro').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            Nome: {
                required: true,
            },
            SobreNome: {
                required: true,
            }
        },


            messages: {
        required: "Campo obrigatório",
        remote: "Please fix this field.",
        email: "Por favor insira um email válido",
        url: "Please enter a valid URL.",
        date: "Please enter a valid date.",
        dateISO: "Please enter a valid date (ISO).",
        number: "Por favor digite apenas números.",
        digits: "Please enter only digits.",
        equalTo: "Please enter the same value again.",
        maxlength: $.validator.format( "Não insira mais do que {0} caracteres." ),
        minlength: $.validator.format( "Digite pelo menos {0} caracteres." ),
        rangelength: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long." ),
        range: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value between {0} and {1}." ),
        max: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}." ),
        min: $.validator.format( "Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}." ),
        step: $.validator.format( "Please enter a multiple of {0}." )
    },
        submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
 $(".resultado_form_cadastro").html('<div class="spinner"></div>');
var form = $('#form_cadastro');

var form_data = new FormData();

var nenhum_tipo = $("#nenhum_tipo").val();
var Bloco_1 = $("#Bloco_1").val();
var Bloco_2 = $("#Bloco_2").val();
var Bloco_3 = $("#Bloco_3").val();
var Bloco_4 = $("#Bloco_4").val();
var Bloco_5 = $("#Bloco_5").val();

form_data.append('nenhum_tipo', nenhum_tipo);
form_data.append('Bloco_1', Bloco_1);
form_data.append('Bloco_2', Bloco_2);
form_data.append('Bloco_3', Bloco_3);
form_data.append('Bloco_4', Bloco_4);
form_data.append('Bloco_5', Bloco_5);
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://xxxx/buscauiva/public_html/admin/form_cadastro.php', // point to server-side PHP script

        //url: 'http://buscaiuva.com.br/admin/validaAcesso.php', // point to server-side PHP script
        dataType: 'text',  // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form_data,
        type: 'POST',

        success: function(php_script_response){
            //alert(php_script_response); // display response from the PHP script, if any
// pegando os dados

        }

     }).done(function(data){
                $('.resultado_form_cadastro').fadeOut('slow', function(){
                    $('.resultado_form_cadastro').fadeIn('slow').html(data);


                });
            })
            .fail(function(){
                alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');
            });
            return false; // for demo
        }
    });
});
```

**PHP**

```
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database");

    mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO tipo_banner (id_empresa, nenhum, bloco1, bloco2, bloco3, bloco4, bloco5)
    VALUES ('".$id_empresas."', '".$_POST['nenhum_tipo']."', 

'".$_POST['Bloco_1']."', '".$_POST['Bloco_2']."', '".$_POST['Bloco_3']."', '".$_POST['Bloco_4']."', '".$_POST['Bloco_5']."')") 
or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

> ```
> <input type="checkbox" name="Bloco[]" value="1" />
> <input type="checkbox" name="Bloco[]" value="2" />
> <input type="checkbox" name="Bloco[]" value="3" />
> ```

```
 var blocos = new Array();
$("input[name='Bloco[]']:checked").each(function ()
{
  blocos.push( $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: voltou um erro Uncaught ReferenceError: Bloco is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (empresas_cadastrar.php:506)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at t.validator.submitHandler (empresas_cadastrar.php:504)
    at s (jquery.validate.js:1)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (jquery.validate.js:1)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLFormElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)

Comment: como adpataria isso no meu código?

Comment: o erro ainda persistiu, você pode mostrar isso em meu código?

Comment: está retornano esse erro agora Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: faltou um pontinho ali rsrs, de novo var Bloco_1 = ''; if($("#Bloco_1").is(':checked')) { Bloco_1 = $("#Bloco_1").val(); }

Comment: ainda está pegando os que nao são selecionados

Comment: Agora é só vc fazer o mesmo para os outros blocos, sacou? Esse exemplo que dei foi para o bloco_1.

Comment: deu certo amigo, obrigado